# How can I use a second PC to replace the requested file on the fly?

Tags: linux, windows, replace, proxy, mitmproxy

Here's the problem:

I have two PCs. One is using Windows 10 and the other is using Linux.
The Windows PC is requesting a file from a third party server. I need to replace it with my file on the fly. Maybe using the second pc as a proxy and something like Man in the middle. I could put my Linux-PC ip in Hosts, but I only need to replace one file, I shouldn't change all other requests.

As an example:
Win-Pc asks the server for a file. Linux-PC acts as a proxy. Somehow linux-pc changes the requested file to my file (without changing its name and extension) and sends it to win-pc saying it's the original file.

The question is how to make linux-pc work as a proxy and how to replace the file

P.S. Both pc are at my place and I have full access to them. That is, I can completely change the hosts and have administrator rights

Comment: Are you talking about http(s)? Any proxy server should support mapping individual pathnames

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to substitute file matching to URL http://zzz.com/123.txt

you need to

1. configure nginx this way:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name zzz.com;

    root /static-files;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ @server;
    }

    location @server {
      proxy_pass http://zzz.com;
    }
}
```

2. and place file 123.txt into /static-files folder.
3. and at windows PC you make override for zzz.com domain name in **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc** so zzz.com would point to linux server IP address:

```
192.168.0.123 zzz.com
```

with such config nginx will intercepts queries matching files located in "root" directory (and serve local copies of those files) and pass through other requests to the real server

Comment: this might be useful, i'll try it